# Polymer 1.0: How can I get the value of the selected item in a paper-dropdown-menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu, polymer, selected, paper-elements

Polymer 1.0: How can I get the value of the selected item in a paper-dropdown-menu?

I am submitting some info with iron-ajax and I can't the value (I don't want the label) from the paper-dropdown-menu.  The id of my paper-dropdown-menu is 'mymenu'.  I have tried these:

```
this.$.mymenu.selectedItem.value
```

Comment: outside of Polymer, in normal JS bind and look for .....  e.currentTarget._selection.selection[0].$yourAttrVals

Comment: But i want to do it using polymer.  Surely the is some way to get the value

Comment: try the debugger to figure it out yourself.. its what i did my first time with selectors and with iron-list

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you set the value in the `value` attribute, the following should work:

```
this.$.mymenu.selectedItem.getAttribute("value")
```

**Update**

For a declarative approach, you can set `attr-for-selected="value"` and then bind to the `selected` attribute.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
    <paper-menu attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{selection}}" class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item value="croissant">Croissant</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="donut">Donut</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="madeleine">Madeleine</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
<div>[[selection]]</div>
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does pre-selecting not work with this solution? For example if you add a property called selection and give it a starting value of "donut" - the dropdown-menu will show blank until a value is manually selected, instead of showing the label "Donut".

Comment: @Inrego Preselect does work for me with this approach. I've tested it in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PbLbqWlTFmUp8vjI2g9e?p=preview)

Comment: I'm trying your plunk @Maria but there seems to bee some issue? The menu is grayed out and nothing happens when I click on it? I guess it should work on Chrome?

Comment: @HaunsTM It looks like the plunk is no longer working due to some depenencies that can no longer be found. The approach described above in the answer should still be ok, though.